# VB.NET If last letter/symbol of a string is a specific symbol

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I've just started getting into a standalone VB programming and I see that there's a lot of differences in code from what I am kind of used to in excel VBA. I have a code in my excel VBA:

```
Dim UserName As String
UserName = Split(Application.UserName, " ")(0)
If Right$(UserName, 1) = "s" Then UserName = Left$(UserName, Len(UserName) - 1)
```

Which is extracting first word of a username and finding if the last letter of that is "s" in which case it trims it off.
I need to do the same thing in VB.NET. WHat I have got so far is

```
Dim UserName As String
UserName = Split(Environment.UserName, " ")(0)
        If Str.Last(UserName) = "s" Then
            UserName = UserName.Substring(0, UserName.Length - 1)
        End If
```

The if statement is not correct and I wonder if someone here could, please, help me with the right if statement for that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know whether a `String` ends with a particular substring, you call the `String.EndsWith` method:

```vb
If UserName.EndsWith("s") Then
```

This is an example of why you ought to spend time reading documentation. If you want to do something with a `String`, you make a quick perusal of the documentation for the `String` class. If you at least look down the member listing, which would take a few minutes at most, then there's a good chance that you see this method and Bob's your uncle. Even if you don't see what you need, either because it doesn't exist in that place or because it's not obvious enough that it is what you need, you haven't lost a lot of time and you might see something else that could be of use use now or later. I've learned a lot this way over the years, so I'm speaking from experience.

Comment: Thank you, mate! That helped me, I figured the trimming part out myself. I see that VB.NET is more "human language"? Since instead of like machine POV it uses more of a human terms. I guess it's a matter of getting used to

Comment: @Eduards, indeed. Moving from one flavour of VB to another is perceived by many to be very easy because of the similarity, but that similarity can sometimes trip you up.

Comment: @Eduards, one thing to keep in mind regarding trimming is that, if you are using the `String.TrimEnd` method, it will remove multiples "s" characters from the end of the text if they are there. That may not be an issue but be aware that `"abcssss".TrimEnd("s"c)` would yield "abc", not "abcsss".

Comment: Oh, yeah I definitally need to trim just one "s"

Answer (score 1):

Function **Right$** is still available, only it is moved to **Strings.Right**. Left$ and Right$ are moved, so that Left$ doesn't get confused with *Form.Left*

Comment: Ah, alright thank you very much, and it is written the exact same way besides that?

Comment: Yes, same arguments. You're welcome.