# Check if the last part of a String is equal to "a"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I check if the last part of a String is equal to "a" so something like this

```
If name1.Length -1.Contains("a") Then
  do something
End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET If last letter/symbol of a string is a specific symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243080/vb-net-if-last-letter-symbol-of-a-string-is-a-specific-symbol)

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, then please [accept the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

```
If name1.EndsWith("a") then
  do something
End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that that's case sensitive. If you want insensitive, `EndsWith("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Gogeaele To thank someone on Stack Overflow you need to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will help future readers, earn the some reps for the one who answered and earn you a couple of points.